# C++ template function to check if a vector of contains the value?

Tags: c++, templates

I had planned to implement a kind of INDEX function for all types similar as in FORTRAN.
Would this be a correct solution?
A little **EDIT** after comments.

```
template <typename T>
bool contains(std::vector<T>& vec, T value){
 if (std::any_of(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [value](T j) { return value == j; }))return true;
 return false;
}
```

**NB**
There is a pitfall with float type comparison for generic implementation!

Comment: when you describe for all types you mean ```std::array```, ```std::vector``` and ```C-like array``` ?

Comment: I intended at least the elementary types, int, float, double, string, ...

Comment: `if (A) return true; else return false;` = `return A;`.

Comment: Aside: I would use the name `contains` for this function. I would expect that `index` return the position that `value` is in `vec`

Comment: Would you modify the vector??? -> Accept it by const reference!

Comment: That is true that the name should be "contains". The "index" can be reserved to return the position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is a valid implementation, however I'd write it differently

```
template <std::ranges::input_range R, typename T>
requires std::indirect_binary_predicate<ranges::equal_to, ranges::iterator_t<R>, const T*>
bool index(R&& range, const T & value){
    return std::ranges::find(range, value) != std::ranges::end(range);
}
```

This will work for any sequence and any value that can be compared for equality with elements of that sequence.

In C++11 there aren't concepts to be explicit about the requirements, but it goes similarly

```
template <typename R, typename T>
bool index(R&& range, const T& value) {
    using std::begin, std::end;
    return std::find(begin(range), end(range), value) != end(range);
}
```

Comment: I tried to use, but failed:
std::vector<string>s={"111","222","3333three","four"};
std::string s1="112";
std::cout<<index(s,s1)<<std::endl;
Will this has to apply to C++11+?

Comment: @MathArt I've used C++20 syntax in this answer. It's similar in C++11

Comment: Can please check here https://ideone.com/a41coh?

Comment: @MathArt that needs a c++20 compiler and `#include <algorithm>` [see here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/513fc0deb8163bc0)

Answer (score 2):

If the objective of your program is to find the determined value that is the correct way:

```
template <typename T>
bool index(std::vector<T>& vec, T value){
  return std::any_of(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [value](T j) { return value == j; });
}
```

My program doesn't differ much from @caleth's answer as in order to write a general-purpose function that can handle various sorts of ranges, such as an `std::array`, `std::vector`, a `C-like array`, or others, you should write a template like this:

```
template <typename iter, typename T>
bool any_index(iter begin, iter end, T value) {
    for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
        if (static_cast<T>(*begin) == value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

usage:

```
int main() {

    vector<int> v1{ 4, 3, 2, 1 };    
    vector<string> v2{ "hey", "language", "compiler", "bug" };
    vector<char> v3{ 'a', 'b','c', 'd' };
        
    array<int, 6> c{ {1,2,3,4,5,6} };
    unsigned char buf[5] = {0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55};
    
    assert(any_index(begin(v1), end(v1), 4) == true);
    assert(any_index(begin(v2), end(v2), string("compiler")) == true);
    assert(any_index(begin(v3), end(v3), 'd') == true);
    assert(any_index(begin(c), end(c), 5) == true);
    assert(any_index(begin(buf), end(buf), 0x11) == true);
          
    return 0;
}
```

Full example ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ncvY5xW7r))

Comment: I checked with:   vector<float> v0{ 4.1f, 3.f, 2.f, 1.12f };   
    cout<<any_index(begin(v0), end(v0), 1.12f); but output to "1"!

Comment: the output value is 1 because the boolean equivalent is ```true```